# Host header Injection/ Host Header Url redirection in Apache2.4

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I configured Apache2 server and disabled the default config file (000-default.conf) and created and enabled my own config file.

Following is the content of my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName xyz.somedomain.com
        SSLUseStapling on
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert/some.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/somekey.pem

        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
        Header unset X-Forwarded-Host
    </VirtualHost>
```

The application is running fine. But if we change the host header and send request to my server (let's say if we change host header to bing.com), then also my server is responding to that request and redirecting to bing.com.

I read that I need to configure a catch all block, but I tried different methods, some of them breaks my website and some doesn't work. I have disabled .htaccess also.

Please let me know how should I proceed.

I tried adding catchall block mentioned as below, but this doesn't work:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost
```

I also tried rewrite rules as in my conf file in sites-available directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !xyz.somedomain.com
RewriteRule ^.(.*) - [L,F]
```

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'xyz.somedomain.com'">
    Deny from all
</If>
```

Ref link: https://www.middlewarebox.com/2020/07/http-host-header-injection-apache-24.html

None of them is working. Apache version is 2.4.41

Answer (score 0):

In levels without `StrictHostCheck` where you're having trouble with virtual host (or other) methods, you could try:

```
RequestHeader set Host xyz.somedomain.com early
```

This should cause the server to act as if the client uses xyz.somedomain.com, even if they didn't.

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't solve the problem. What is expected is if someone send request to my server by changing domain (Host Header redirection) it should return as access denied. If I run the following command:

 curl -k --header 'Host: evil.com' https://xyz.somedomain.com

 My apache server should not process this request and return access denied or something.

 However in my case the server is doing the redirection.